# Built in dell keyboard backlights not working

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, dell, backlight

I have a Dell Inspirion e4310, and it came with windows 7, and the keyboard backlight worked. But I put Ubuntu on it instead, and now the back lights don't work at all. I have tried using the

```
sudo xset led 3
```

command to no avail. Two directories exist in my */sys/class/backlight*. Here's the file tree:

```
├── acpi_video0 -> (Symbolic Link)
│   ├── bl_power
│   ├── brightness
│   ├── device -> (Symbolic Link)
│   ├── max_brightness
│   ├── power
│   ├── subsystem -> (Symbolic Link)
│   ├── type
│   └── uevent
└── intel_backlight(Symbolic link)
    ├── actual_brightness
    ├── bl_power
    ├── brightness
    ├── device -> (Symbolic Link)
    ├── max_brightness
    ├── power
    ├── subsystem -> (Symbolic Link)
    ├── type
    └── uevent
```

Comment: May I know the output of `ls /sys/devices/platform` ?

Comment: I've had several Inspirons, including a e4310 and I've had zero backlight problems with Ubuntu (16.04 LTS or older). So just to make sure: the backlight *is* working when you boot into BIOS and it's not disabled there?

Answer (score 2):

I think the /sys/class/backlight directory is for the display backlight, not the keyboard backlight.

I don't have an e4310, but in case it helps, on my xps 9560 using kernel 4.15.3, the keyboard backlight controls are in /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight. In particular the /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/start_triggers file should contain "+keyboard +touchpad". My keyboard backlight wasn't coming on, and it turned out that the start_triggers file contained "-keyboard -touchpad". The minus sign indicates that the relevant device is disabled.

There is more info about the various other files in this directory at https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/rafael/linux-pm/+/78d425677217b655ed36c492a070b5002832fc73%5E1..78d425677217b655ed36c492a070b5002832fc73/

Answer (score 2):

I have a dell xps 9370 and a few days ago the keyboard light turned off. 
My /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/start_triggers contained "keyboard +touchpad" so I changed the value from 0 to 1 (50% of light) of the file /sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness

Answer (score -1):

try "Fn+Right Allow" key

Comment: what is a "Right Allow" key?